# PL/SQL Developer on Citrix doesn't update date/time stamp on local files

Tags: plsql, citrix

I am using PL/SQL Developer on a Citrix server.  I keep my SQL files on my local hard drive so I can retain more control over them.

However, I have noticed that when I modify a file and save it, the changes are saved in the SQL file on my local hard drive but the date/time stamp on that file is NOT updated.  So I have SQL files that I changed this morning (4/2/2013 10:03 am) but the date/time stamp still reads 3/22/2013 4:44 pm

I have made changes using Textpad, UltraEdit and Notepad and the everything is fine.  So it appears to be specific to PL/SQL Developer.

I have also determined that TOAD and SQL Developer also don't update my date/time stamp.

Has anyone else encountered this weird issue?

Comment: Citrix is Windows 7 Enterprise SP1.  My local machine is XP Pro Ver 2002 SP3  I have connected to Citrix from a Windows 7 client and encountered the same problem.

Comment: I have a feeling this is Citrix issue.  I haven't ever tried running PL/SQL Developer under Citrix, but in the past we had some issues when running VB apps that way.  Have you tried contacting Citrix support?

Comment: I contacted Citrix support and they gave me nothing. They told me it was an issue with the database (which made no sense to me) and when I followed up they told me it was an issue that they would not address and I should contact my IT group. I have worked with my IT group and we have not come up with anything yet (not for a lack of trying). One thing I just noticed is that the date/time stamp on the folder IS being updated. Which makes this even stranger to me.